# Has the Federal Reserve been propping up stock prices since March 23 2020?

Tags: united-states, finance

I happened upon [this r/askeconomics post](https://redd.it/i1ct31) that hasn't been answered.

In [*The Hill*](https://thehill.com/opinion/finance/504009-are-you-angry-with-the-fed-you-should-be), [Thomas Lyns](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/directory/lys_thomas.aspx) of Northwestern Univ and [Daniel Taylor](https://accounting.wharton.upenn.edu/profile/dtayl/) of UPenn's Wharton proclaim

> So, where does all the Fed money go if it isn’t trickling down to labor markets and consumers? It is being reinvested in financial assets, inflating their value. This explains why we are facing record unemployment not seen since the [1930s](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/19/unemployment-today-vs-the-great-depression-how-do-the-eras-compare.html), but yet equity valuations are now higher than they have been at any time over the past [15 years](https://www.wsj.com/articles/its-no-optical-illusionu-s-stocks-really-are-expensive-11591009200).

[Newsweek](https://redd.it/hzzyc0) quoted [Royal Holloway, University of London](https://pure.royalholloway.ac.uk/portal/en/persons/jeff-frank(0d0fd142-7eaf-4eb8-9cde-8e768aad1c30).html) Prof. [Jefferson Frank](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeff-frank-789431a7/?originalSubdomain=uk)

> ### Education
>
> - Reed College. Bachelor's degree. Economics and Philosophy
> - Yale University. PhD.  Economics
>
>   Supervised by James Tobin
>   'A Disequilibrium Model of Inflation and Unemployment'

> Originally set to expire on September 30, Treasury Secretary Steven Mnuchin said on Tuesday it would extend its suite of lending programs to businesses, governments, and individuals to the end of the year.
>
> However, Frank said the Fed's purchase of junk bonds has distorted the market economy because "the problem at the moment is that risk is not calculable."
>
> "**Pouring liquidity into the markets to raise stock prices** or trying to change the risk premium on relatively high-grade junk bonds by a modest amount does not help get funding to the shut or partially-shut restaurant on Main Street," he said.

[Mohammed El Erian](https://www.fnlondon.com/articles/an-audience-with-mohamed-el-erian-i-dont-need-a-job-for-money-20190830) wrote the same thing [on May 29 2020.](https://foreignpolicy.com/2020/05/29/stock-market-rally-coronavirus-pandemic/)

> **Education**
> 1985: DPhil economics, University of Oxford
> 1982: MPhil economics, University of Oxford
> 1980: BA economics, University of Cambridge

> What is driving markets is a bet investors believe they can’t lose: They win if—based on the notion that stock markets can see past the short term—the economy quickly returns to normal; they also win if it doesn’t, given that the U.S. Federal Reserve has repeatedly demonstrated that it is both willing and able to backstop markets. After all, what is more reassuring than a buyer with a seemingly endless appetite and a money-printing press to boot?

At [0:11 of this CNBC video on Jan 5 2016](https://www.cnbc.com/video/2016/01/05/richard-fisher-real-issue-in-china.html), former Dallas Federal Reserve President Richard Fisher said

> [What the Fed did — and I was part of that group — is we front-loaded a tremendous market rally, starting in 2009. March 2009.](https://thegreatrecession.info/blog/fed-official-confesses-fed-rigged-stock-market-collapse-certain/)

These four contradict Paul Krugman who said ["I don't think the Fed has really driven up valuations so much as it has...It's avoided a plunge in valuations." And "whether the subsequent rise has much to do [with the Federal Reserve's stimulus starting Mar 23 2020], I don't think so."](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/37963). Who's correct?

Comment: Are you asking if their actions have actually accomplished this (possibly unintentionally), or are you asking if this is a current policy goal?  I can see either condition being true without the other.

Comment: I meant to ask "if their actions have actually accomplished this (possibly unintentionally)". Thanks for descrying this distinction!

Comment: I don't know how one could possibly establish causation from a sample size of 1.  There may be theory to suggest that their actions should have caused this effect, but this site is supposed to be about empirical evidence.

Comment: Why this question is problematic, meaning primarily opinion-based: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35918/do-any-governments-or-central-banks-have-an-explicit-or-econometrically-probab

Comment: OTOH the direct buying by the FOMC of corporate debt [is unprecedented](https://reason.com/2020/06/30/stock-market-suspiciously-healthy-the-federal-reserve-does-all-it-can-to-keep-economic-reality-from-setting-in/). In some hindsight, I think not even the Chinese did this, back in 2015 when the US press was [mocking them](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/07/09/upshot/the-problem-with-chinas-efforts-to-prop-up-its-stock-market.html)...